# Vanilla session serialization with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, session-cookies

I have a university project to make, and one of the things I need to do is to make a functional login module with session serialization.
The problem is though that I have to do this without using express or other Node.js modules that are not vanilla'is enough, and well, I just can't find anything on this without using express, or passport, or session-serialize module or some other modules that do not seem too vanilla'ish to me.

Is there a way to do this right?

I'm thinking of this:

1. Validating login data
2. Generating some random id ( a cookie session id thingy )
3. Storing this inside my database
4. Storing this inside my cookies

> ( though I've noticed that cookies from a route will be different from
>   cookies on another route, so if the authenticated user comes on a
>   page he has not been before, so there's no cookie of the session
>   there, he may not appear as logged in )

5. Using that cookie to make requests to the database so the user can see whatever he needs.
6. Generating a new id for when the user logs in from another machine without this cookie session id
7. Deleting this cookie session id when the user pressed log out

Comment: What are the exact (non-self-imposed) restrictions on what you can use? Starting without at least a router (like Express, even though it adds some bad ideas on top of that) is kind of annoying for not a lot of practical benefit.

Comment: What you present (1-7) sounds reasonable and easily doable. If you have any issues with that, come back with an acual question. This one is just too broad to answer.